# Printing multimap within multimap (nested maps)

Tags: c++, dictionary, nested, multimap

I am trying to print out a nested multimap but haven't found a way (or a discussion here) to help me solve the problem.

They way I normally print a multimap looks something like this:

```
template<typename a, typename b>
void printMMap1(std::multimap<a, b>thing){
 for (std::multimap<a,b>::iterator it = thing.begin(); it != thing.end(); it++){
    std::cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << std::endl;
  }
}
```

But now I want to use the same motivation to print a:

```
multimap<multimap<a,b>, multimap<c,d>> MAPname;
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
template<typename aa, typename bb, typename cc>
void printMMap(std::multimap<std::multimap<aa, bb>, std::multimap<aa, cc>>thing){
    for (std::multimap<std::multimap<aa, bb>, std::multimap<aa, cc>>::iterator it = thing.begin(); it != thing.end(); it++){
    std::cout << it->first.first << " : " << it->first.second << std::endl <<
            it->second.first << " : " << it->second.second << std::endl;
}
```

}

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thank you for your help.

***_EDIT:***

Using motivation from hansmaad's example, I came up with something close to the solution I would like (below):

```
//N.B: I removed the "auto"s for educational purposes (mostly for myself and other beginners)

template<typename a, typename b>
void print1(const std::multimap<a, b>& thing){
for (std::multimap<a,b>::const_iterator it = begin(thing); it != thing.end(); it++){
   std::cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << std::endl;
   }
}



template<typename aa, typename bb, typename cc>
void print2(const std::multimap<std::multimap<aa, bb>, std::multimap<aa, cc>>& thing){
std::multimap<std::multimap<aa, bb>, std::multimap<aa, cc>>::const_reverse_iterator it = thing.rbegin();

//why reverse iterator? Because I noticed that the loop which duplicates the output has a final iteration equal to the desired output, so I only use the last iteration i.e. going backwards ("rbegin")

std::multimap<aa, bb> keyMap = it->first;
std::multimap<aa, cc> valueMap = it->second;

std::cout << "key\n";
print1(keyMap);
std::cout << "value\n";
print1(valueMap);

}
```

This prints this solution, which is 90% close to what I want. For e.g. it prints:

```
key
a_key1 : a_value1
a_key2 : a_value1
a_key2 : a_value2
a_key2 : a_value3
a_key3 : a_value1
a_key3 : a_value2
a_key3 : a_value3
a_key3 : a_value4

value
b_key1 : b_value1
b_key1 : b_value2
b_key1 : b_value3
b_key1 : b_value4
b_key2 : b_value1
b_key3 : b_value1
b_key4 : b_value1
b_key4 : b_value2
```

Whereas I want to print the same output, albeit formatted like so:

```
key                  value 
a_key1 : a_value1    b_key1 : b_value1
a_key2 : a_value1    b_key1 : b_value2
a_key2 : a_value2    b_key1 : b_value3
a_key2 : a_value3    b_key1 : b_value4
a_key3 : a_value1    b_key2 : b_value1
a_key3 : a_value2    b_key3 : b_value1
a_key3 : a_value3    b_key4 : b_value1
a_key3 : a_value4    b_key4 : b_value2
```

A slight difference. I smell I am close.

Comment: What did you mean by this doesn't seem work?

Comment: Well, like hansmaad stated later, multimap<aa,bb> && multimap<aa,cc> dont have 'first' as a member. I want to print ==> "key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value3," etc., but i can only accomplish ==> "key1 : value1, key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value3," etc. It duplicates the output. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you expect as output from your `printMMap` function, but the problem with your code is `it->first.first`

```
template<typename aa, typename bb, typename cc>
void printMMap(std::multimap<std::multimap<aa, bb>, std::multimap<aa, cc>>thing){
    for (std::multimap<std::multimap<aa, bb>, std::multimap<aa, cc>>::iterator it = thing.begin(); it != thing.end(); it++){
            // std::multimap<aa, bb> x = it->first;
            // std::multimap<aa, bb> y = it->second;
            // x, y don't have a member 'first', they are multimaps
            // broken:
            std::cout << it->first.first /*...*/ it->second.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You could do for example:

```
template<typename a, typename b>
void print(const std::multimap<a, b>& thing){
    for (auto it = begin(thing); it != end(thing); ++it){
        std::cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename aa, typename bb, typename cc>
void print(const std::multimap<std::multimap<aa, bb>, std::multimap<aa, cc>>& thing){
    for (auto it = begin(thing); it != end(thing); ++it){
        auto& keyMap = it->first;
        auto& valueMap = it->second;
        std::cout << "key\n";
        print(keyMap);
        std::cout << "value\n";
        print(valueMap);
    }
}
```

Which will print for

```
    multimap<multimap<int, int>, multimap<int, int>> mmap;
    multimap<int, int> key{ { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 4 } };
    multimap<int, int> value{ { 10, 1 } };
    mmap.emplace(move(key), move(value));
    print(mmap);


>key
>1 : 1
>1 : 2
>2 : 4
>value
>10 : 1
```

Comment: Thanks hansmaad! The problem I have with your code was a problem I had as well when I tried something similar. What you have now is a loop inside of a loop, which duplicates the output I was planning on outputting. Does that make sense? And do you have any idea how to print without a duplicate?

Comment: Hi hansmaad: I want to print something like ==> "key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value3," etc., but i can only accomplish ==> "key1 : value1, key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value3," etc. It duplicates the output.